# Calculate how many ways you can give $7$ children $7$ identical candies

Tags: combinatorics

**My try:**

> Calculate how many ways you can give $7$ children $7$ identical candies if each child got at most 2 candies.

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7=7 \text{    for   } x_i \in \left\{ 0,1,2\right\}$$
$$[t^7](1+t+t^2)^7[t^7](\frac{1-t^3}{1-t})^7=[t^7](1-t^3)^7 \sum {n+6 \choose 6}t^n$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|}
\hline
\text{first parenthesis} & \text{ways in the first} & \text{ways in the second }\\ \hline
\text{1} & 1 & { 13 \choose 6} \\ \hline
{t^3} & { 1 \choose 1} & { 10 \choose 6} \\ \hline
{t^6}  &  { 7 \choose 2} & { 7 \choose 6}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Sollution:$${ 7 \choose 2}{ 7 \choose 6}+{ 7 \choose 1}{ 10 \choose 6}+{ 13 \choose 6}=3333$$
But I checked it in Mathematica and I get $393$. So can you check where the error is?

Comment: Have you ever met any children? (I suppose you probably did when you were one yourself.) There is exactly one way to distribute seven candies to seven children, as any parent knows.

Comment: @TonyK Under the terms of the task, each child can get $ 0-2 $ candy

Comment: When you expand $(1 - t^3)^7$, the signs should alternate.  Yours do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was commented, the only issue is the sign of the middle term must be negative. To see it, express the first binomial as a sum too:
$$[t^7](1-t^3)^7 \sum {n+6 \choose 6}t^n=[t^7]\sum_{k=0}^7{7\choose k}(-t^3)^k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+6 \choose 6}t^n=\\
\underbrace{{7\choose 0}{13\choose 6}}_{k=0,n=7}-\underbrace{{7\choose 1}{10\choose 6}}_{k=1,n=4}+\underbrace{{7\choose 2}{7\choose 6}}_{k=2,n=1}=393.$$

Answer (score 3):

There is a much simpler method to solve this problem. Generally these sort of problems are classified as NP and can only be solved numerically.

OK! Back to the question, you can give each child exactly **one candy** which is possible in **1 way**.

You can give 2 candies to one of them in 7 ways and the rest at most 1 candy each, in $\binom{6}{5}$ ways, totally leading to **42 ways**.

You can give 2 candies to two of them in $\binom{7}{2}$ ways and the rest at most 1 candy each, in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways, totally leading to **210 ways**.

You can give 2 candies to three of them in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways and the rest at most 1 candy each, in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, totally leading to **140 ways**.

Adding up all the cases, leads to a total of **393 different ways**.

Comment: Good answer for "how to solve this" (+1) but not really an answer to "where did I go wrong".

Comment: Thank you. Honestly I did not get what you've done. Would you elaborate on it a little?

Answer (score 2):

The solution will be confficent of $\,t^7 $ in the
expension of $${(1\, - \ t^3)}^7{(1 - t)}^{-7}$$
I.e coefficient of $t^7$ in $( \,1 - \, {7 \choose 1} t^3\,+{7 \choose 2} t^6)(1\,-t)^{-7}$ $$
= \,{13 \choose 7} \, - 7\,{10 \choose 4}\,+21{7 \choose 1} $$
= 393